# "The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null " for JSON data in jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

While generating jasper reports in java using JSON data, the following error occurs.

```
The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null
```

I know it requires a connection but I am using JSON data to fill the report. Here is my code

```
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("filepath");
    InputStream iostream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("AMOUNT", json.getString("AMOUNT"));
    parameters.put("CGST", json.getString("CGST"));
    parameters.put("IGST", json.getString("IGST"));
    parameters.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, iostream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream  pdfReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(pdfReport)); 
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It gives the error when i'm trying to fill the report. I already made **JSON_INPUT_STREAM** and pass through the map.Have no idea how to pass the connection.Any help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if you also post the jrxml file.
But, in theory, you have to options:

First of all, see if you use in the jrxml file the parameter REPORT_CONNECTION (or smth like this, this is the default param jasper creates when you create a new report).

Now:

1. if you do and not need it, because you are not taking anything directly from the bd, fix the code in your jrxml.
2. if you do and really need it, use something like this to send it:

   ```
   Connection conn;
   try {
       DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection (connection_url, user, password);
       ......[your code]
       jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
       jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
       ......
   } catch (Exception ex) {}
   ```